# Covering knob holes in bathroom tile

Tags: bathroom, tile, remodeling

I have recently replaced an old leaking shower manifold (three handle) with a one handle model. In hindsight I should have used an adapter plate like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GAMNZI) to cover the two outer holes and expose one larger hole in the middle. Instead, thinking I would cover two holes I might as well cover three, so I moved the new knob up to a more comfortable height and cut a new hole, installing the new manifold and knob there. This is now all working.

I still have the three holes from the old knobs. I'm wondering the best way to cover them. I was thinking about finding a few pieces of decorative tile (each slightly larger than a hole) and affixing them over each hole. If I do this, how would I affix the tile? I'm assuming I would caulk around them after doing so, but would caulk be enough for hold ([This thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/55792) gives me pause)? Can you think of other ways to cover the holes? Note of course that the tile is old and certainly cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

If you do choose to use tile, you could use silicone caulk as the adhesive. It will bond well and is waterproof, you will need to secure it with tape and perhaps lean a heavy object against it to hold it in place until it cures. Make sure the surfaces are clean and dry, and use apply a bead of silicone caulk around the entire perimeter of each piece to prevent water intrusion to the underside.